# Translate query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query:

```
public function upShops() {
DB:statement('update shops set position = 
(SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at), 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at) ORDER BY points desc, created_at desc ) FROM (select * from shops) as shop_rankings)))');
}
```

How I can this query translate to eloquent Laravel? I think that need do so:

```
Shop::update(['position' => '(SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', 
created_at), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at)'])-
>orderByDesc('points')->orderByDesc('created_at');
```

But this does not work. I get an error in the update method. How I can do eloquently correctly?

Comment: "_I get error in update method_" Can you post that error? In your question, not the commeents please. Bracket count maybe? Counting  9 `(` and 5 `)`

Answer (score 0):

Update eloquent method returns a boolean, true on success otherwise and error, and therefore you cannot chain methods like `orderByDesc` to it. 
An example of how to update would be something like:

```
Shop::update(['position' => 'value']);
```

Comment: How then I can translate my query to eloquent?

Comment: You can do this in two stages update, then fetch with the above command.

Comment: Can you Give a example?

Comment: `Shop::update(['position => value'])`  , `Shop::orderBy('points', 'desc')->get()`, I think this will do.

Comment: ) No. Please see my query, I have `CONCAT` methods

Comment: Well what exactly do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

How about this (I have added table aliases in selections of subquery for more clarity)?

```
\DB::table("shops")
    ->update([
        "position" => \DB::raw("(SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(shops.points, '_', shops.created_at), 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(shop_rankings.points, '_', shop_rankings.created_at) ORDER BY points desc, created_at desc ) FROM (select * from shops) as shop_rankings)))")
]);
```

Comment: But Can I use: `Shop::update`  instead `\DB::table`?

Comment: If you want to update all record then you need to use `\DB::table` as `::update` can not be called statically and directly to a model. You can call it on an instance or eloquent collection.